# Set up a simple audio live stream with mp3s from folders

Tags: streaming

I want to have an audio live stream on my website, that all the visitors hear in sync. My idea:

1) Upload mp3s to server
2) Server plays audios from folder as playlist
3) Visitors hears current audio playback from server

The only script I found was https://github.com/gadgetguru/PHP-Streaming-Audio but it seems to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following setup and test the RTMP streaming if you're familiar with AWS.

1. Create a bucket in your S3 account which is all in lower case, is
   globally unique and is DNS-compatible; For example, a bucket called
   media.xxxxxx.com.au’.
2. Then to make it all look nice you need to create a DNS CNAME entry
   to map a sub-domain of your site to that S3 bucket.
3. Upload a test file test.mp3 to the S3 bucket. Now the file uploaded
   would be accessible via http://media.xxxxxx.com.au/somefile.mp3. You
   do just need to set the ACLs on the files & the bucket to make sure
   public access is allowed.
4. Finally, to stream audio files via a Flash player from S3 to another
   domain, you also have to tell Flash that it’s ok for the content to
   be pulled in from a different domain. Create a file called
   ‘crossdomain.xml’ in the bucket, with these contents:

   ```
   <cross-domain-policy>
   <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
   </cross>
   ```
5. That allows the media to be accessed from anywhere - you can be more
   specific if you want but this is the simplest approach.
6. you can use Amazon CloudFront on top of your S3 bucket. Create a
   "streaming distribution" in Cloudfront that points to your S3
   bucket.  This will stream via RTMP (good for web and Android devices). You can use JW Player or a similar player to play the streamed files. Cloudfront Streaming uses Adobe Flash Media Server.There is also the ability to play secure content using signed URLs.
7. Use this site https://www.hlsplayer.net/rtmp-player to test your
   Amazon setup.